# Text alignment using whitespace and the pre tag

Tags: html, css

How do I align add this text properly?

my code :

```
 data[0]=hello 123
 data[1]=hellowq 345
 data[2]=heloowaaa 678
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     obj += "<pre><li>" + data[i] + "</li></pre>";
 }
```

my actual input :

```
hello            123
hellowq          345
heloowaaa        678

output :
hello            123
hellowq            345
heloowaaa           678
```

I would like to get output like this:

```
hello            123
hellowq          345
heloowaaa        678
```

Comment: what data comes with `data[i]` ..? You probably needs to modify the layout to get that type of visual..

Comment: Can you pride some other code?

Comment: i mentioned input in hello            123
hellowq          345
heloowaaa        678

Comment: So; data[0] in this case would be the string

    "hello            123"?

Do you build up the data-strings somewhere and accidentally add spaces by just adding the same amount of spaces to each?

Comment: You have problems in your input, cause event with your invalid HTML it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7vyy83du/

Comment: Can you try using a 'border-less' table for displaying the output?

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML, the *only* valid child of either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` is an `<li>` element; the `<pre>` elements should be *within* the `<li>` elements:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    obj += "<li><pre>" + data[i] + "</pre></li>";
}
```

And the CSS for the `<pre>` elements set to `white-space: pre-wrap` (or similar), this is the usual default styling of that element, but it's possible that the defaults have been overwritten or set differently in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

As I claimed in the comments, you probably add the same amount of spaces to each label/value-pair. The solution is probably in the code we don't see where you would have to subtract the length of your label+value from the number of whitespaces generated.

A better way to do this would be to layout in html/css instead. A quick and dirty example.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Domdido <span class="value">$8</span></li>
    <li>Domdido123 <span class="value">$8</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{list-style:none;padding-left:0;
    width:50%;
}
.value{float:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqs2rvrd/

Comment: single string only aligned like this not separate value

Comment: data[0]=hello            123
data[1]=hellowq          345
data[2]=heloowaaa        678

Comment: Yea, and since you say 'extra spaces added in script' I figure you got enough control over it to split them into separate values. Else, as I said, you have to modify the 'extra spaces added'-part. :)